# Gracefully Remove K3S Node

Tags: k3s

After installing 2 master nodes according to the [k3s docs](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/ha-embedded/) we now want to remove one node (don't ask).

We know that if we shut down one node, the entire cluster "dies". No services accessible, no Kubernetes API available.

Is there a way to gracefully remove a node and return to a single node (embedded etcd) cluster?

Theoretically it must be possible since during installation we started with a working, single node cluster.

Comment: Looks like `k3s --cluster-reset` would be one way of reducing a multi-node (embedded etcd) cluster to a single node cluster.